# Perl sort on numbers

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

I have some perl script to process a file (contains lots of numbers) line by line.

File content (sample data, first 3 numbers are seperated by space, then the seperate is tab between 3rd and 4th numbers):

```
1 2 3 15
2 9 8 30
100 106 321 92
9 8 2 59
300 302 69 88
....
```

Script content:

```
# snippet of script
open(INF, "$infile") || die "Unable to open file $infile: $!\n";
@content = <INF>;
close(INF);

foreach $line (@content) {
    # blah blah, script to handle math here
    # Now the numbers are stored in separate variables
    # $n1 stores the 1st number, i.e.: 1
    # $n2 stores the 2nd number, i.e.: 2
    # $n3 stores the 3rd number, i.e.: 3
    # $n4 stores the 4th number, i.e.: 15
    # Solution code to be inserted here
}
```

I would like to:

1. Sort the variables $n1, $n2, $n3 and output them in ascending order.
2. At the end of foreach, get rid of duplicates

My approach:

```
# Insert below code to foreach
$numbers{$n1} = 1;
$numbers{$n2} = 1;
$numbers{$n3} = 1;
@keys = sort { $numbers{$b} <=> $numbers{$a} } keys %numbers;
#push @numbers, "$keys[0] $keys[1] $keys[2]";
$numbers2{"$keys[0] $keys[1] $keys[2]"} = 1;
```

This defines two hashes: 1st hash is for sorting, 2nd hash is for removing duplicates after sorting.

Is there any better approach?
Thanks,

Comment: so you don't want to keep the fourth number at all?  what are you doing after you get rid of duplicates; in particular, do you need to go through the results in some order?

Comment: http://perlmaven.com/unique-values-in-an-array-in-perl

Comment: Am I understanding this right  -- you want to sort and remove duplicates for numbers on each line, yes?  (So some lines end up having fewer numbers.)

Comment: I don't want to keep the 4th number at all. And there is no duplicates number, but there is duplicate line after the sort. For example, line 2 and line 4 would be identically "2 8 9" after the sort.

Comment: @dellair  Thanks for the clarification, I see now that line.  I've updated the answer so that it treats this case.  Note that I `split` the line to make `$n1` etc, for testing -- your code shouldn't need that, remove it. Let me know if more/better explanation for it is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** with another solution -- it is the lines that may be duplicate, not numbers on a line.

---

In order to remove duplicate lines it is easiest if we have all sorted lines of three numbers in an array. Then we post-process that by running them through `uniq`. There are (at least) two ways to do this.

- Store lines in an array, each being a reference to a sorted array with the three numbers. Then for comparison construct a string of each on the fly.  This is better if there is yet other processing of numbers somewhere along, as they are in arrays.
- Build a string out of each sorted line and store those in an array. Then it's easier to compare.

Below I use the first approach, assuming that there is other processing of numbers.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature wq(say);
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

my $file = 'sort_nums.txt';
my @content = do {
    open my $fh, '<', $file  or die "Can't open $file: $!";
    <$fh>;
};

my @linerefs_all;
foreach my $line (@content) {
    # Calculations ... numbers stored in ($n1, $n2, $n3, $n4)
    my ($n1, $n2, $n3) = split '\s+' $line;   # FOR TESTING 
    # Add to @rlines a reference to the sorted array with first three
    push @linerefs, [ sort { $a <=> $b } ($n1, $n2, $n3) ];
}
# Remove dupes by comparing line-arrays as strings, then remake arrayrefs
my @linerefs = map { [ split ] } uniq map { join ' ', @$_ } @linerefs_all;
say "@$_" for @linerefs;
```

Using the posted lines in the file `sort_nums.txt`, the code above prints

```
1 2 3
2 8 9
100 106 321
69 300 302
```

Explanation of the post-processing line, *read from the right.*

- The [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) on the right processes a list of arrayrefs. It dereferences each and [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html)s its elements with a space, forming a string for the line. It returns a list of such strings, one per line.
- That list is pruned of duplicates by [`uniq`](http://search.cpan.org/~rehsack/List-MoreUtils-0.415/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm#uniq_LIST), which itself returns a list, fed into the `map` on the left.
- In that `map`'s block each string is [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) by (the default) white space into a list (of numbers on the line), and then a reference of that is taken by `[ ]`. This `map` thus returns a list of references to arrays, one for each line, what is assigned to `@linerefs`.

This is then printed.
If this is too much to stomach for one statement break the process into steps, generating intermediate arrays. Or switch to the second method above.

---

*Initial post, assuming that numbers on each line may be duplicates*

I take the objective to be: sort three variables and keep only unique ones, for each line.

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

foreach my $line (@content) {
    # Calculations, numbers stored in ($n1, $n2, $n3, $n4)
    my @nums = uniq sort { $a <=> $b } ($n1, $n2, $n3);
    say "@nums";
}
```

Remember that after this you don't know which one(s) of `$n1`, `$n2`, `$n3` may have been dropped.

---

If, for some reason, a non-core module is not suitable, see [`this in perlfaq4`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-remove-duplicate-elements-from-a-list-or-array?)  For example,

```
my %seen = ();
my @nums = sort { $a <=> $b } grep { ! $seen{$_}++ } ($n1, $n2, $n3);
```

or, if you need it without an extra hash around

```
my @nums = do { my %seen; sort { $a <=> $b } grep { !$seen{$_}++ } ($n1, $n2, $n3) };
```